# What are the default innodb google cloud mysql settings?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am specifically needing information on the innodb_log_file_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size. The link below is the only info I could find but it doesn't mention the settings I'm looking for. I don't require the ability to edit the setting (though that would be nice) I'm just really interested in what Google has decided to set as the secret default value.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

Comment: Have you tried asking a running MySQL instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented anywhere, but you can easily figure this out by creating the instance, connecting to it and executing `SHOW VARIABLES;`. That would return all the MySQL settings.

Please note that some of them, most notably innodb_buffer_pool_size, would depend on the instance size. Also they may change over time as we work on performance.